# resize the popup for different windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you can help me, what happens is that I made a popup, but the problem I have is the screen relationship since from the laptop it looks good, but from a computer it does not meet the screen relationship, I don't know where I can adjust to adapt to different screens, I hope you can help me, I detail the code and the css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var id = '#dialog';
    
        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
    
        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
        
        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  
    
        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
              
        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
    
        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     
    
    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     
    
    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     
    
});
```

```css
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#26262c;
  display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:850px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#boxes #dialog {
  width:470px; 
  height:auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.agree:hover{
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.popupoption:hover{
    background-color:#D1D1D1;
    color: green;
}
.popupoption2:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- PopUp Automatic --> 
<div id="boxes">
<div style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window"> 
<div id="san">
<a href="#" class="close agree"><img src="landing/images/close.png" width="25" style="float:right; margin-right: -6px; margin-top: -44px;"></a>
    <img src="landing/images/popup_2022.jpg" width="450">
<!-- <img src="landing/images/comunicado.jpg" width="450"> -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport units and max/min properties:

```
#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  max-width:440px;
  max-height:850px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding, a query, that applies when viewed in different windows, to make it responsive

Comment: It is responsive. https://jsbin.com/puxoloyilu/edit?html,css,js,output